# Tifffile.imshow() KeyError: 'matplotlib.pyplot'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tiff

I used the Tifffile module's imshow () method to display the tiff image in Python 3.5.2.

The code is as follows:

```
import tifffile as tiff

IM_ID = '6120_2_2'
im_rgb = tiff.imread('/home/roy/image&csv/image/{}.tif'.format(IM_ID)).transpose([1, 2, 0])
im_size = im_rgb.shape[:2]
tiff.imshow(im_rgb)
```

But there is an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roy/PycharmProjects/CSV2Ploy/csv2ploy.py", line 49, in <module>
    tiff.imshow(im_rgb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py", line 6349, in imshow
    pyplot = sys.modules['matplotlib.pyplot']
KeyError: 'matplotlib.pyplot'
```

I think it must be my development environment missing the **matplotlib.pyplot** module. So I checked the matplotlib directory, but found that the directory does have **pyplot.py** file.

[The terminal queries the pyplot.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZYOT.png)

I have a lot of information on the Internet, but most are **import matplotlib.pyplot** problems, some people can help me solve this problem?

Comment: Did you actually try to `import matplotlib.pyplot`? The problem will be completely different depending on whether this succeeds or not.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for your advice！You solved my problem！

Comment: answer your question or delete it and mark the answer as accepted